# python delete specific line and re-assign the line number

Tags: python

I would like delete specific line and re-assign the line number:

eg:

```
0,abc,def
1,ghi,jkl
2,mno,pqr
3,stu,vwx
```

what I want: if line 1 is the line need to be delete, then
output should be:

```
0,abc,def
1,mno,pqr
2,stu,vwx
```

What I have done so far:

```
f=open(file,'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f.open(file,'w')
for line in lines:
    if line.rsplit(',')[0] != 'line#':
        f.write(line)
f.close()
```

above lines can delete specifc line#, but I don't konw how to rewrite the line number before the first ','

Comment: Are these lines being read from a text file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You might have noticed the downvotes on your question.  This is because you did not add what you've tried to code for yourself thus far.

Comment: sorry, i am new to here. I have posted what i did below

Comment: Thank you for your help. I love this place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that will do the job.

```
def removeLine(n, file):
    f = open(file,"r+")
    d = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for i in range(len(d)):
        if i > n:
            f.write(d[i].replace(d[i].split(",")[0],str(i -1)))
        elif i != n:
            f.write(d[i])
    f.truncate()
    f.close()
```

Where the parameters `n` and `file` are the line you wish to delete and the filepath respectively.

This is assuming the line numbers are written in the line as implied by your example input.

If the number of the line is not included at the beginning of each line, as some other answers have assumed, simply remove the first if statement:

```
 if i > n:
        f.write(d[i].replace(d[i].split(",")[0],str(i -1)))
```

Comment: Works! I appreciate your help!

Comment: Just find one problem, if the line number is 2 digital, there is a bug. Eg, Both of LINE 1 and LINE 11 will be change, Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your account wasn't created in the past few hours, so I figure that there's no harm in giving you the benefit of the doubt.  You will really have more fun on StackOverflow if you spend the time to learn its culture.

I wrote a solution that fits your question's criteria on a file that's already written (you mentioned that you're opening a text file), so I assume it's a CSV.

I figured that I'd answer your question differently than the other solutions that implement the [CSV reader library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and use a temporary file.

```
import re
numline_csv = re.compile("\d\,")

# substitute your actual file opening here
so_31195910 = """
0,abc,def
1,ghi,jkl
2,mno,pqr
3,stu,vwx
"""
so = so_31195910.splitlines()

# this could be an input or whatever you need 
delete_line = 1
line_bank = []

for l in so:
    if l and not l.startswith(str(delete_line)+','):
        print(l)
        l = re.split(numline_csv, l)
        line_bank.append(l[1])

so = []
for i,l in enumerate(line_bank):
    so.append("%s,%s" % (i,l))
```

And the output:

```
>>> so
['0,abc,def', '1,mno,pqr', '2,stu,vwx']
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a line number for each line, you should use the enumerate method...

```
for line_index, line in enumerate(lines):
  # line_index is 0 for the first line, 1 for the 2nd line, &ct
```

In order to separate the first element of the string from the rest of the string, I suggest passing a value for *maxsplit* to the split method.

```
>>> '0,abc,def'.split(',')
['0', 'abc', 'def']
>>> '0,abc,def'.split(',',1)
['0', 'abc,def']
>>>
```

Once you have those two, it's just a matter of concatenating `line_index` to `split(',',1)[1]`.